# Распаковка архива tar.xz

Tags: архивация, ubuntu

Столкнулся с архивом типа tar.xz. Что это такое и как это распаковывать?

Comment: Скорее всего tar и есть, но совсем не обязательно. Чтобы быть уверенным стоит посмотреть содержимое. По первым символам сигнатуры чаще всего можно определить формат. Т.к. это может быть произвольный файл с любыми данными и совсем не обязательно архив.

Comment: Если ОС Windows тогда 7zip вам в помощь

Answer (score 17, accepted):

xz - это файловый формат сжатия данных с помощью алгоритма LZMA. Чтобы использовать на Убунту, надо установить xz-utils.

Установка:

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

Распаковка:

```
tar -xpJf archive.tar.xz
```

Comment: Мне казалось, там уже все для этого есть. По крайней мере, в FreeBSD это можно делать без установки дополнительного ПО.

Comment: У меня сработало буз установки доп. пакетов(Ubuntu 16.04) так: `sudo tar -xvf ARCHIVE -C PATH`

Answer (score 7):

В дальнейшем, чтобы не заботится о том, какой тип архива, можно поставить утилиту atool:

```
$ sudo apt-get install atool
```

Для распаковки (покажу на примерах):

```
$ aunpack a.7z
$ aunpack a.tag.gz
$ aunpack a.zip
```

Для архивации:

```
$ apack a.7z file1.txt file2 dir1
```

Для просмотра содержимого:

```
$ als a.7z
```

и др.

Answer (score 3):

есть и универсальное решение.

во всех популярных дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu/linux* есть пакет *dtrx* («do the right extraction»). при его установке по зависимостям будут установлены и недостающие в системе распаковщики.

программа самостоятельно определяет, что находится внутри файла, и умеет распаковывать tar, zip (включая самораспаковывающиеся .exe), cpio, rpm, deb, gem, 7z, cab, rar, файлы, созданные InstallShield, сжатые gzip, bzip2, lzma и compress.

при обнаружении внутри архива других архивов/сжатых файлов, программа интерактивно предложит распаковать и их.

использование:

```
$ dtrx сжатый.файл.и.или.архив
```

---

[страница разработчика](http://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/)

[man dtrx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/dtrx.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

На Linux есть `unar`, распаковывающий все подряд и нормально обрабатывающий русскую кодировку в `zip`. Для `tar.xz` тоже подходит.